# How to create a jQuery-Ajax-Request but not send it right away to the server

Tags: jquery, ajax, mootools

In Mootools, I can create an AJAX-request and save it in a variable for further use. When I create the request, I can send it later by calling

```
myRequest.send();
```

or

```
myRequest.get();
```

In jQuery, whenever I create an AJAX-request, it is sent right away to the server. Is it possible to create a request without sending it at the same moment?

Comment: Sure, just wrap it in a function, and call the function later !

Comment: You mean Synchronous?

Comment: Some things about MooTools are ready "out of the box". Request in MooTools is a Class and you can "prepare it" and fire the `.send()`method when you want. With jQuery you cannot do that, you either fire it ritgh away, or create another function with a ajax funcion inside and pass it parameters when you call it. I prefer the MooTools way...

Comment: So do I, that's why I asked the question. I will add your comment as the solution

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30440328/57091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sergio and @adeneo stated above in the comments:

> Some things about MooTools are ready "out of the box". Request in
>   MooTools is a Class and you can "prepare it" and fire the
>   .send()method when you want. With jQuery you cannot do that, you
>   either fire it ritgh away, or create another function with a ajax
>   funcion inside and pass it parameters when you call it. I prefer the
>   MooTools way...

Thanks!